# Mapping to Wordpress server with RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

Im trying to send a JSON to a local Wordpress server, the mapping I have is the one below:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];

RKObjectMapping *orderEntryMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];

[orderEntryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"title": @"title"
                                                        }];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptorOrderEntry = [RKRequestDescriptor  requestDescriptorWithMapping:orderEntryMapping objectClass:[OrderSend class]   rootKeyPath:@"posts" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptorOrderEntry];
```

The OrderSend class is the one below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OrderSend : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *title;

@end
```

and this is the method that is sending the request:

```
-(void) submitOrder:(OrderSend *) order completionHandler:(ResultObjectHandler) completionBlock
{

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{
               @"json" : @"posts.create_post"
               };


[objectManager postObject:order path:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result)
 {
     NSLog(@"We object mapped the response with the following result: %@", result);
     completionBlock(result);
 }
                  failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     [self handleFailure:operation withError:error];
 }];    
 }

-(void) cancel{

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
}

-(void) handleFailure:(RKObjectRequestOperation *)operation withError:(NSError*)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
}
```

Im using the JSON API for Wordpress, but Im getting this error:

```
{NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths     searched., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested   object representations at the key paths searched: categories, posts
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: error, status
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings.,   keyPath=null, DetailedErrors=(
)}
```

Can anyone help me please?, thanks in advance

The solution was to create a Response Descriptor like the code below:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorOrderEntry = [RKResponseDescriptor     responseDescriptorWithMapping:orderEntryMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil     keyPath:@"" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
 [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptorOrderEntry];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a request descriptor, but you aren't defining a response descriptor. So, RestKit doesn't know what to do with the response.

You need to create a response descriptor with an associated mapping so that RestKit knows how to apply the response. By default RestKit will try to apply the response data to the source object (`order`), but it needs to know how to do that...

Comment: thanks a lot, that actually worked, I will edit to put the solution for future references